# Blender for competition?

Tags: performance, unreal-engine, polycount, rendering

I am in a competition. I am literally 2 weeks into game dev, and rarely use Blender. I normally just use it for a brief tutorial, and if it works, it works, if not, I just forget about. So the question came up, for my very low spec laptop don't use brushes in unreal engine 4, because they require tremendous performance in the end result. Instead, I am to create my cyberpunk city in Blender, do everything I want in it, transfer it to unreal engine 4 and then make my HD picture.

I don't have the first clue of the knowledge that they're drawing on to say this. I suggested just plastering 2k jpegs on everything and calling it a day. They said it would look terrible, and not win me the competition. The competition requires a picture or a cutscene.

So the question is, Yes use blender? And could you explain it, like i'm a 3 year old?

LAPTOP SPECIFICATIONS:
Product number 4RV10UA

Product name HP Notebook - 15-db0004dx

Microprocessor AMD Ryzen™ 3 2200U (2.5 GHz base frequency, up to 3.4 GHz burst frequency, 1 MB cache, 2 cores)

Memory, standard 8 GB DDR4-2400 SDRAM (1 x 8 GB)

Video graphics AMD Radeon™ Vega 3 Graphics

Hard drive 1 TB 5400 rpm SATA

Optical drive DVD-Writer

Display 15.6" diagonal HD SVA BrightView WLED-backlit (1366 x 768)

Keyboard Full-size island-style keyboard with numeric keypad

Pointing device Touchpad with multi-touch gesture support

Wireless connectivity 802.11b/g/n (1x1) Wi-Fi® and Bluetooth® 4.2 combo

Network interface Integrated 10/100/1000 GbE LAN

Expansion slots 1 multi-format SD media card reader

External ports 2 USB 3.1 Gen 1 (Data Transfer Only); 1 USB 2.0; 1 HDMI 1.4b; 1 RJ-45; 1 headphone/microphone combo

Minimum dimensions (W x D x H) 37.6 x 24.6 x 2.25 cm

Weight 2.08 kg

Power supply type 45 W AC power adapter

Battery type 3-cell, 41 Wh Li-ion

Battery life mixed usage Up to 7 hours and 30 minutes

Video Playback Battery life Up to 6 hours and 15 minutes

Webcam HP Webcam with integrated digital microphone

Audio features Stereo speakers

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's clear from your question what specifically are you asking about.. If you mean "can one make a scene like shown one in Blender and maybe Substance for texturing" then the answer would be yes except that for that kind of work low-end laptop is a no-go in anyway. You could try to create objects for that scene separately in different files however even then you have to have resources to preview your work

Comment: Yes, is there any way to recreate that gif, working with a low end laptop, be it in blender or unreal-engine. or is my idea of just pasting 2k jpgs everywhere the answer?

Comment: [This video might help you.](https://youtu.be/xWq-ZPMhai8) And having a lot of images on an old laptop might not be the best idea.

Comment: Well you could start by stating exact specifications of the laptop you have; "low end" is quite subjective. You can [edit] your question to include more info. It also depends on what end goal is; putting a picture on a plane won't be necessarily realistic and can work usually only on distance. Note that images also need memory which also means resources.

Comment: I added the laptop specifications.

Comment: Those specifications are not really "low-end" and generally will do for modelling animating and probably even rendering when previewing materials. However it will be far from enough if that scene should be modelled and put together for rendering. E.g Vega GPUs aren't supported with Cycles afaik so render will be slower. Competition also means working on time and your hardware will not be working as fast as for others likely, look at 32 GB RAM. This question is not for Blender.SE format. I'd suggest asking on https://blenderartists.org